# Is mmap a built in function?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, glibc

I know that *mmap* is a system call, but there must be some wrapper in glibc that does the system call. Yet when I try to use *gdb* to step through the *mmap* function in my program, *gdb* ignores it as it can't find any source file for it (Note I compile my own glibc from source). I can step through other glibc library functions such as *printf* and *malloc* but not *mmap*. I also use the flag *-fno-builtin* so that gcc doesn't use built in functions. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to *step into* mmap to start with? The bug is elsewhere :-)

Comment: Jens I don't want to step into mmap to see some bug, but just to see where is the code for mmap so I can make some modifications. What I plan is to log the parameters for each system call including mmap. Yes, I know there are other ways, but I am writing some special tool.

Comment: `strace` might be helpful in this case. Also check the source code of `strace` to see how it accomplishes the same job as you want to do here.

Comment: Then I suggest grepping the Linux kernel source tree for 'mmap'. That should turn up the right file(s).

Comment: strace uses ptrace. I am interested in the mmap wrapper that does the system call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what your problem is. It works perfectly fine for me.

Using system `libc.so.6`, with debug symbols installed:

```
// mmap.c
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
  void *p = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  return 0;
}

gcc -g mmap.c


$ gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40052c: file mmap.c, line 5.

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at mmap.c:5
5         void *p = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
(gdb) step
mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:83
83      in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
(gdb) 
main () at mmap.c:6
6         return 0;
(gdb) q
```

Using my own glibc build:

```
gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40056c: file mmap.c, line 5.
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at mmap.c:5
5         void *p = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
(gdb) step
mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81      T_PSEUDO (SYSCALL_SYMBOL, SYSCALL_NAME, SYSCALL_NARGS)
(gdb) 
mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82              ret
(gdb) 
main () at mmap.c:6
6         return 0;
(gdb) q
```