# How to tell gcc to stop using built-in functions?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, glibc

I am using my own modified glibc. I saw in the compiled code that compiler was not using many standard library functions from my glibc when I linked with it. Then I put `-fno-builtin` flag. Things got better and I could see that many functions which were not taken from glibc were now taken from there, such as `malloc`.

However, still for many functions, such as `mmap`, the compiler is using some built-in-code. Now how can I ask the compiler to please exclusively use the code from glibc rather than using its built-in-functions?

On my x86-64 function, if I do objdump of the compiled glibc, following is the generated mmap function. I can't find equivalent code in the glibc source.

```
0000000000000000 <__mmap>:
   0:   49 89 ca                mov    %rcx,%r10
   3:   b8 09 00 00 00          mov    $0x9,%eax
   8:   0f 05                   syscall 
   a:   48 3d 01 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
  10:   0f 83 00 00 00 00       jae    16 <__mmap+0x16>
  16:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: There is no built-in mmap() in gcc. You may want to use -O0 and disable inlining.

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684381/is-mmap-a-built-in-function help?

Comment: It calls into kernel using `syscall` instruction. It's not a built-in function.

Comment: Maxim: I know its a system call, but there must be a wrapper in user space somewhere. No?

Comment: "there must be a wrapper" --- this *is* the wrapper. Load the syscall number to %eax, invoke the syscall instruction. Doesn't have to be anything more than that.

Answer (score 6):

The wrapper you disassemble above comes from the INLINE_SYSCALL macro in 
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h.  This macro is the 'magic glue' used to turn a normal function call into a system call.

As part of the build process of glibc, for every defined system call `foo` that is not in a list of special exceptions for that architecture, it generates a function `__foo` that contains just a single `INLINE_SYSCALL` macro invocation.  `mmap` is not in the exception list for x86_64 (in sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscalls.list), so it gets the generic treatment.

Answer (score 2):

How about passing "-ffreestanding" to gcc as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612556/4726668) answer?

Comment: I'm trying `-ffreestanding` and it still seems to use a lot of builtins.  For instance, `__mulsi3` or other calls on really low-end systems.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a call to `mmap` compiles to on my system:

```
movl    $1048837, 20(%esp)
movl    $1048836, 16(%esp)
movl    $1048835, 12(%esp)
movl    $1048834, 8(%esp)
movl    $1048833, 4(%esp)
movl    $1048832, (%esp)
call    mmap
```

I have used some constants like 0x100100 (1048832) as `mmap` arguments in order to be able to find corresponding instructions in the assembly easier.

This looks like pretty ordinary call to a pretty ordinary library function, and not a builtin.

The actual code for `mmap` is OS- and architecture-dependent. For instance, for i386 Linux it is in `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/mmap.S` (yes it's written in assembly).

Comment: I am using x86-64 system. Can't find any correspoding code for that. Edited the question to show the generated mmap.

Comment: What you have displayed does look like the code for `mmap`. What your `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/mmap.S` says?

Comment: No its not that code. And ofcourse i386 is not used for x86-64 code.

Comment: I suggest you recompile the `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux` directory and see for yourself which source file is responsible for `mmap.o`.