# Difference between -ffreestanding and -nostdlib when compiling with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, x86, linker

I am using a 64 bit linux machine with a x84-elf64-gcc compiler. I have just started low level programming and would like to understand how C code is actually translated into binary. This is mainly for Operating Systems developement, as I know that a processor doesn't understand ELF, or any other format, and only understands binary.

For example, the following c file:

```
//test.c
int func()
{
    return 0x12345678;
}
```

When I compile with gcc:

```
gcc test.c
```

I get the following error:

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I'm guessing that there is an issue with the linker.
I do:

```
gcc test.c -c
```

I get an ELF object file, and I do an objdump and get the expected:

```
0000000000000000 <func>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   b8 78 56 34 12          mov    $0x12345678,%eax
   9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   a:   c3                      retq
```

But when I "cross compile" a 32 bit version using the *-m32* option and objdump, I get:

```
hello.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <func>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <func+0x4>
   8:   05 01 00 00 00          add    $0x1,%eax
   d:   b8 78 56 34 12          mov    $0x12345678,%eax
  12:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  13:   c3                      ret    

Disassembly of section .text.__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax:

00000000 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>:
   0:   8b 04 24                mov    (%esp),%eax
   3:   c3                      ret
```

I've read in a previous answer that this has to do with position independent code: [undefined reference to `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_' in gcc 32-bit code for a trivial function, freestanding OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070109/undefined-reference-to-global-offset-table-in-gcc-32-bit-code-for-a-trivial)

Why is there such a change when you compile with the -m32 option?
Moreover, I was advised to use the *-ffreestanding* option when I compile, but it doesn't seem to have an effect here. I've read that *-ffreestanding* tells the compiler that there is no standard library, so what is -nostdlib then?

Note: I'm relatively new to this *hardcore* c programming, and I think that the main issue here is that I don't really understand how linkers/compilers work. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options control two parts of the process:

- [-freestanding](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-ffreestanding-1) indicates to the compiler that it should be a freestanding one, AFAIK the only effect is disabling some built-in functions like *memcpy*;
- [-nostdlib](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-nostdlib) indicates that no libraries and no start up files should be linked by default.

Comment: So isn't -nostdlib an option to be used with ld? Why is it used with gcc?

Comment: `gcc` is usully used as a wrapper, calling `ld` itself.  (`-c`, `-S`, `-E` and perhaps other options stops the process before the link).

Comment: `-ffreestanding` also prevents some CRT startup and teardown option from being linked IIRC (when passed to `gcc` when linking).

Comment: @rubenvb, it does not seems so, at least when playing a little with `-v`, `-ffreestanding` and `-nostdlib` with the classical hello world.

Comment: @SuraajKS: `-nostdlib` controls what other files *gcc passes to `ld`*.  `ld` on its own doesn't linking any files that aren't on its command line.  That's why gcc has to explicitly pass CRT start files and `-lc` to `ld`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `-ffreestanding` does *exactly*, that part is a good question.

But unfortunately your question has a big side-track into 32-bit PIE code:

> Why is there such a change when you compile with the -m32 option?

Because you left out any `-O` optimization option, and 32-bit mode doesn't have an EIP-relative addressing mode for data (only relative jumps/calls).  So apparently debug-mode always sets up a register as a GOT pointer as a base for addressing static data, even in functions that don't use it.

Always use `-fno-pie` to turn off that default unless you specifically *want* to make a PIE executable.

You might also want `-mcmodel=kernel` - that's a good idea if you're compiling a 64-bit high-half kernel (static addresses can be used a 32-bit sign-extended immediates, but not 32-bit zero extended).  But IDK if it does anything for 32-bit code.

Comment: As far as I know, a 32 bit machine does not even have an RIP, isn't it EIP? I've done a bit of assembly programming and I think that simple function calls usually use instruction pointer relative addresses to jump/branch. Why is it said that 32 bit mode doesn't have relative addressing??

Comment: @SuraajKS: The EIP/RIP-relative data addressing mode was new with x86-64.  It's not available in 32-bit mode.  I guess I could have said "no EIP-relative addressing mode" because if it existed in 32-bit mode that's what it would be.  Yes call and jmp are encoded as `rel32` or `rel8`, but that's separate from *data* addressing modes in a ModRM.

Comment: So in other words... Instructions like jmp used(could use) relative addresses while memory accesses (eg. mov eax,[location]) used absolute?

Comment: @SuraajKS: In 32-bit mode, yes.